# unnable to install package "Forecast"

Tags: forecast

Following is the output from R console:

> library(forecast)
>   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’
>
> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zoo_1.8-0           colorspace_1.3-2    parallel_3.2.1      tools_3.2.1         nnet_7.3-9          yaml_2.1.14         Rcpp_0.12.10
 [8] fracdiff_1.4-2      ggplot2movies_0.0.1 grid_3.2.1          tseries_0.10-40     timeDate_3012.100   lattice_0.20-31     quadprog_1.5-5

Answer (score 0):

Which version of R are you using now?. Can you update your R version and try re-installing the forecast package with `install.packages("forecast", dependencies = TRUE)`

Thanks.